# Strange mesh deformation when using the action editor?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I have had this problem before and it's starting to happen again, but with a different mesh. 
Note that it is scaled up a tiny bit.

When I create a new action called reload and animate only the hands it works, but as soon as I click on a different object and move the timeline bar it deforms **everything**:

[image: click the timeline and move it a bit...]

There are no object constraints on anything and there is only one armature modifier on the arm. Other than that I have nothing.

[YouTube video demonstrating the problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTaR7jnJ1-o&feature=c4-overview&list=UU28bfUuaupS-1mzytSUmlrw)

Comment: Very odd result, would be a lot of guessing without having the blend file to look at.

Comment: should i give it to you with paste all or something?

Comment: I will give it to you tomorrow

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/9hmlkjpw4hnba3c/UMP45_BTarms4problem.blend ... PLEASE dont use these for yourself ( you prbably wont anyway ) but .. yeah hers the files PLEASE help me... oh yea make sure to add a cube and make that part of the animation - it should also deform -___-

Comment: I'm not having this issue in the latest build of Blender. Try downloading the latest trunk build from: http://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: ahhhh ill just wait till it releases sorry :)

Comment: @Knuckles209cp I really think you should provide the exact blend file as you record that video. It seems that we cannot help you more without it (the file you uploaded is a bit different). Before that, have you tried the latest build as CharlesL provided yet? Btw, you got two Armature modifiers on the arms. It may cause the issue like this.

Comment: TO WHOEVER SAID I SHOULD RIG THE GUN - PLEASE ANSWER AND I WILL REWARD THE REP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple: your object hands center is static on animation while your armature not (not in the pose animation, the object like is) . Your armature had rotations like your hands for apply, for that when you create the key animation everything shows, looking bad. If you make the hands parent like object to the armature the effect is not show looking correctly, but everything turn up by the turn of the armature.

The file needs some clean out and normal logic using armatures. It's normal if you are starting on Blender:

- The objects to be used with an armature usually had the same object center
- You must apply any rotation or size using control +A and "rotation &scale"
- Usually the hands must be child of his armature (make it more easy for move)

At end, for a fast solution (this correct your problem): Your hands had the action animation of reload linked to them. That make problem if I try to put some locrotscale key, because that will affect to both objects at same time, looking bad again. Quit assigned animations to object hands (not armature) selecting them and change "dopesheet" menu  to "action editor". Now,  press X next to name "ReloadUMP". Try to move your first bone and works , but not if you move the armature like object.

[image: hands like child of armature, but like the armature turns, the animation goes up, must apply scale and rotation before]

NOTE: I had the file fixed, but you will not learn nothing then...

Comment: *sigh* This question didn't had a bounty on it? So bad...

Answer (score 1):

While you can manually add an armature modifier to an object and set it up to work, the most common method is to start by setting the armature as the parent of the mesh object. While the armature is the parent, moving it in object mode will also move the mesh with it, keeping things aligned.

Once an armature is setup to deform a mesh object moving one of them without the other gives a weird deformation as seen in your screenshot. Even if the armature is the parent you can move the mesh object by itself and get the same bad deformation.

The further apart you move the armature and the mesh the worse the distortion is.

If you have the armature as the parent of the mesh then be sure to move the armature and not the mesh.

If you don't want to use parenting then you need to make sure you move both the armature and the mesh together.

Also scaling one without the other can produce the same result.

That applies to moving the two objects in object mode not moving the armature in pose mode.

One thing to watch is if you use automatic keyframing, you need to make sure you turn it off when you finish animating.

Comment: Whoa! thank you so much for the long answer ! i will try this out now!

Comment: hmmm none of these are working? I do realise that that the deform ONLY happens if i add a keyframe to the gun the move it ... maybe that would help?

Comment: If the gun object is joined to the arms making them one object then it will be the same as moving the arms without the armature. Making the gun a parent of the arms will also get the same result. When you add a new cube to make the gun are you in object mode or edit mode for the arms?

Comment: sorry i dont really understand what you said , but i appended my gun from another .blend file and added it to my hand file and saved it has something else. if that helps - oh and when i animate the armature is in pose mode(when i add keyframes) , and the arm is in object mode

Comment: im uploading a youtube video showing my problem

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTaR7jnJ1-o&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Log into the RenderFarm chat room (chat link down below) or would you prefer irc?

Comment: whats irc? is it for chat